# Using Javascript to set class of parent node with child's text equal to ...?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to set the class of several `<tr>` elements to `reset`. This should be done by JavaScript. I know that in general manipulating nodes with JavaScript is easy as this:

```
function changeclass() {
  var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
    trs[i].className = "reset";
  }
};
changeclass();
```

Now I tried to restrict the selection of `<tr>` elements to those that entail a `<td>` that has text equal to `reset` with the following line doing he selection instead of `document.getElementsBy...`, which utterly failed:

```
var trs = document.evaluate( "//td/tr[text()='reset']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Now I do not know what the problem is, wrong approach? Flaw in my understanding of Javascript?  ... ? ... any hints would be appriciated.

Comment: So if they only have "reset" in them, or if they simply _contain_ "reset"?

Comment: Try with `document.querySelectorAll`, it'll save you some headaches

Comment: @elclanrs Afaik querySelectors can't retrieve innerHTML of an element, they just do queries based on the element's properties/attributes.

Comment: @Teemu: I'm not sure what you mean. `querySelectorAll` gives you a `NodeList` just like `getElementsByTagName`, so all you have to do is loop.

Comment: @elclanrs I mean, that basicly OP want's to find a row, which has a `td` containig the text "reset". querySelectors can't find text within elements, can they? - Nevermind, after seeing your answer I know what you meant : ).

Comment: No method that fetches DOM elements can find text, all they do is fetch elements, and working on those elements is the same either way, wether the nodeList is gotten with querySelector or any other method, but some return just one element, others a nodeList.

Comment: You need `element.querySelector` that returns a `Node`, that's all.

Comment: Also there's [element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) to query more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct expression is

```
 var trs = document.evaluate("//tr[td/text()='rest']", document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

also you can access nodes by `trs.iterateNext()`

**Update**

after document changing results will be no longer valid. so you can push them in an array and use it after all `iterateNext()`.

```
var trsx = document.evaluate("//tr[td/text()='rest']", document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var trs = [];
if (trsx){
    var tr = trsx.iterateNext();
    while(tr){
            trs.push(tr);                   
            tr = trsx.iterateNext();                
    }               
}

for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
    trs[i].className = "reset";
}
```

or you can use other XPathResult type.

```
var trs = document.evaluate("//tr[td/text()='rest']", document.body, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
if (trs){
    for(var i=0; i<trs.snapshotLength; i++){
        tr = trs.snapshotItem(i);
        tr.className = "rest";                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm and accepted as answer because although others posts work too and are elegant this one shows how to use XPath to get it done.

Comment: Unfortunately not a cross-browser solution (IE).

Answer (score 4):

Do it the other way around: find the tds, then access the parents:

```
var tds=table.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i=0;i<tds.length;i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.indexOf("reset")>=0){
        tds[i].parentNode.className="reset";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, `<td>` elements are only permitted as children of `<tr>` elements, so this works perfectly.

Comment: Interesting and without any further need of scripts ... out of curiosity what is that ``indexOf("reset")>=0`` part though?

Comment: It basically means "contains the string reset"

Comment: @marvin_dpr if you need a strict equal, you can use (tds[i].innerHTML=="reset") instead

Answer (score 1):

JQuery

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $('tr td').each(function(){
      if($(this).html() == 'reset') {
        $(this).parent().addClass('reset');
      )
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use jquery and the following code:

```
$("tr>td").each(function () {   
    $(this).parent().attr('class','reset'); 
});
```

Comment: The questioner wants it on the `<tr>` element, not `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeclass() {
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
        var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td'),
            txt = trs[i].innerHTML.indexOf('reset') != -1;

        if (txt && tds.length) trs[i].className = "reset";
    }
}

changeclass();
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
// Query elements as real arrays
var query = function(selector, element) {
  element = element || document;
  return [].slice.call(element.querySelectorAll(selector));
};

var trs = query('tr').filter(function(tr) {
  return query('td', tr).filter(function(td) {
    return td.textContent.trim() == 'reset';
  }).length;
});
```

Now `trs` is an array of all `tr` that contain a `td` with text `"reset"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeclass() {
  var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // It has at least one

  for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
   if (trs[i].firstChild.tagName=="td"&&trs[i].firstChild.text="reset") {
    trs[i].className = "reset";
  }
}
};
changeclass();
```

this will work on `tr`s that only have first child with tag `td`

Sources:

- http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_firstchild.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_tagname.asp

Comment: @PollyGeek but this will not select only those whose text equals 'reset' - right?

Comment: now it should work , i was just making sure that all your TRs have TDs , cause if ones dont have the condition will be false then .